# How to connect apollo server to a remote mongo instance of an application deployed with mup

Tags: mongodb, meteor, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

So I have application A and Application B, I want to connect to the mongo instance of application B (through apollo server) which is deployed with mup in another server. By default, you cannot connect to the mongo instance of an application deployed with mup from outside. I tried setting bind_ip=0.0.0.0 in mongo config and set the necessary users and passwords but no luck.

The connections work find if all applications are running in the same server.

Comment: You need to provide a more detailed explanation of your issues.

Comment: And please only add the _relevant_ tags. I heavily doubt that your connection problems arise from the use of GraphQL.